# Flash duplication of an Object - Cloning library?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, clone

This is probably a very simple question, I just don't have the foggiest how to go about it.

I have an Object that I want to duplicate, and don't know how to go about it. Here's my attempt:

```
var myObj = new ObjectClass();
var duplicate = myObj;
duplicate = null;
myObj.function(); // Error: Null reference
```

The ObjectClass is very large, inherets and creates children of it's own, and I'm sure there's probably a few singleton classes in there.

Is there a way to duplicate something easily?

**Edit:** Looks like I'm looking for "Cloning", for which there is no AS3 function, and you apparantly can't clone Private data anyway. Anyone know of a library or a workaround for cloneing a bunch of private data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this util function from some blog, can't remember from where so I can't give the credit. It wouldn't work with bitmapdata though. Anyway here it is:

```
public static function copy(o:Object):Object 
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray( );
    bytes.writeObject( o );
    bytes.position = 0;
    return bytes.readObject( );
}
```

Usage:
registerClassAlias("com.tests.TestClass", TestClass);
var testCopy:TestClass = TestClass(ObjectUtil.copy(test));

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to do the trick. Thanks so much!!

Appears to be from this blog: http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2007/08/on-transient-objectutilcopy-and-casting.cfm

Comment: As noted below that works to copy public properties but doesn't work with private properties.

Comment: The code above is the actual implementation of Flex's ObjectUtil.copy() method, so if you're working in Flex, you can use the ObjectUtil class directly instead of using above code.

Comment: Ah yes, very true. It doesn't copy private properties.

Comment: You would need to make a custom clone function for your ObjectClass, which is probably better. Maybe by using the copy util to clone public properties, and then manually cloning the private ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectUtil.copy()` (a Flex library).  But you are right that it doesn't support private data.  So this is a shot in the dark but I wonder if you serialize it to AMF using `ByteArray.writeObject()` if that will copy the private data?  Might be worth trying.

Comment: I just tried the ByteArray approach and that doesn't seem to work.  Sorry.