# ActionScript - General Undo / Redo API?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, list, undo-redo

i've been unsuccessfully attempting to create my own undo/redo classes that work well with any type of possible undo and redo commands.

for example, my simple class works perfectly with undoing/redoing x and y positions of display objects or undoing/redoing values of sliders, etc., but things get dicey when i try to tailor my classes to also work with things like adding and removing items to a list.

is there any well known and *well documented* solution for general undoing and redoing for actionscript (without Flex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific design patters for this kind of stuff in AS3

Please check the following links:
http://lucamezzalira.com/2010/01/12/memento-pattern-in-actionscript-3-undoredo/

you can also check Command pattern, which is the de-facto standard ,irrespective of the programming language, it would give you the basics.

Incase you face any issues, please feel free to comment.

Comment: thanks for this.  i've read thru the source code of the example in your link and the class i wrote works nearly identical.  the problem i'm having is that while it's easy to save and reference a property value for the dragged window, i can't seem to get how i could save and reference and added or removed list item  - even with the example from the link.  any ideas?

Comment: For big items like lists, you should clone the object, and store it for future reference.For cloning AS3 object you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832732/flash-duplication-of-an-object-cloning-library